# How to handle numbers in NLP task

Tags: natural-language, word-embeddings

I am doing some NLP task, which will first turn words into embedding vectors.

However, if there are numbers in sentences, then they are seemed as "unknown word", and lose their representation of numbers or values.

Is there any method handling numbers?

Comment: if you learn embeddings for numbers as well, then you don't have to treat numbers as 'unknown words'. Google News word2vec pre-trained embeddings contain entries for numbers: see the bonus app here and try to enter a number: https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/

Comment: @Antoine, thanks for your comment. I tried the app, it works when I type number like '8', '3'. However, it seems cannot handle number like '134572'. Do you have any thought about numbers like that?

Comment: numbers such as '134572' have much likely never been seen in the training corpus (their probability that you encounter such numbers in a given document is very low), so as a result they don't have any entry in the model.

Comment: I think this raises question raises an important point. I work in the financial sector and the numbers in the text is half the meaning. My own thinking (haven't tried it yet) is that I need to add the numbers back in afterwards as if they are additional features